# Wrong data type - Generics

Tags: java, generics

In the below Java code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestGenericMethod {

public static <E> void ArrayToArrayList(E[] a, ArrayList<E> lst) {
    for (E e : a) lst.add(e);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer[] intArray = {55, 66};  // autobox
    ArrayToArrayList(intArray, lst);

    for (Integer i : lst) System.out.println(i);    
    String[] strArray = {"one", "two", "three"};

    //ArrayToArrayList(strArray, lst);   // Compilation Error
}
}
```

Can someone explain me how does the compiler know that this line:

```
ArrayToArrayList(strArray, lst);
```

throws an exception ?

If the method accepts a generic type of data why does it accept an Integer array but not a String array ?

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't compile because `ArrayToArrayList` expects an array and an array list **of the same type (`E`)**:

```
public static <E> void ArrayToArrayList(E[] a, ArrayList<E> lst) {
```

Your commented-out example tries to call it with an array of `String` and an `ArrayList` of `Integer`.

The following does compile:

```
      String[] strArray = {"one", "two", "three"};
      ArrayList<String> strLst = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayToArrayList(strArray, strLst);
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect such a quick response. It makes more sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static <E> void ArrayToArrayList(E[] a, ArrayList<E> lst)
```

In this method, the type of the `ArrayList` passed should be of **same type** as the type of your array **(E)**

So, if you are passing `ArrayList<Integer>`, you have to pass an `Integer[]`, as you have used same type `E` for both of them.

Now in this invocation: -

```
ArrayToArrayList(strArray, lst);
```

your `lst` is of type `ArrayList<Integer>`, and your `strArray` is `String[]`, so there is a `type mismatch`.